# Jmeter test with infinite loop in 'loop controller',constant runtime and 'constant timer'.What are the advantages and how to tune with this approach

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing

I have setup a jmeter script with constant runtime set in runtime controller, infinite loop in loop controller and a constant delay between threads in'constant timer'. How can I perform tuning using this setup? Is there a correlation between '*no of threads*', '*rampup time*' and '*delay*' that should be kept in mind while trying different combinations of these values for performance testing?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Add some code.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cijGX.jpg

Comment: This is the structure of my jmeter script

Comment: I started with 100 thread count, rampup 5 seconds and delay 50 ms, got throughput as 200.But  when I increased rampup to 60,with the same 100 thread count,delay 50 ms config- I got 217 rps. When I increased the thread count to 200 with delay 50 and rampup 120, I got 223.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Number of threads` is basically the number of users you will be simulating. Each JMeter thread (or virtual user) must represent a real user using your application so treat it this way. If you have a requirement that the application must support 1000 concurrent users - stick to this number as the baseline for your testing. With regards to ["how much load will my N JMeter users generate"](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420695-How-do-I-Correlate-the-Number-of-Concurrent-Users-with-Hits-Per-Second#control) - it depends on several factors like nature of your test, server response time, timers,
2. `Ramp-up` is the time for JMeter to kick off the virtual users from point 1. Unless you're doing [spike testing](http://www.testingperformance.org/definitions/what-is-spike-testing) you should be increasing the load **gradually** as if you release all the users right away you will get much less information and in case of gradual increasing the load you will be able to correlate it with increasing response time and decreasing throughput, number of errors, etc. Moreover it will allow to "wamp up" application under test and it will be more ready for the stress
3. `Delay` is time the virtual user is "thinking" between operations. Real users don't hammer application non-stop, they need some time to "think" before making the next step. Depending on what the user is "doing" the think time might be different so I would recommend going for [Uniform Random Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Uniform_Random_Timer) instead of the "Constant" one.

Comment: Does the delay means that the if a thread is up, it start keeps http request in regular intervals(delay), no matter if response is obtained for the previous response or not

Comment: JMeter always waits for response from previous request prior to starting new one

Comment: I havent set response timeout in the test.Does that mean that jmeter will wait until a response from the server

Comment: It means that if JMeter will not receive response from the server within the bounds of specified timeout - it will fail the request, otherwise JMeter will wait infinitely

Comment: I observed a behavior today in my test. For 200 threads, 80 constant delay 30 rampup time and 1000ms connection timeout,I got 379122 success responses and 514 errors (Total 379636 requests). But on rerunning the tests with same configs with only difference in delay which I changed to 40 ms,I got 487039 success and no error. What I was thinking is that , as the delay is decreased by half. Isn't it the total request count be increased to double. But here the total requests count is only increased by around 10000.

Comment: JMeter sends requests as fast as it can so the main factor is not the constant delay but rather application response time.

Comment: JMeter always waits for response from previous request prior to starting new one .Does that mean whatever be the delay between requests set, jmeter will send requests only after a response is obtained from previous request.

Comment: JMeter will wait for previous response, then it will wait for specified delay time then execute the next request

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please suggest a good tutorial or online course for jmeter

Comment: The best tutorial is the official [User Manual](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/index.html), if you're looking for an online course - try out [JMeter Academy](https://www.blazemeter.com/jmeter-tutorial)